# Posting photo to user's photos offlne using facebook php api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

To post a photo to logged in user's photos these are the api function parameters:

```
$result = $facebook->api('/me/photos/', 'post', $attachment);
```

I would like to post a photo in offline mode using this:

```
$result = $facebook->api('/'.$user_id.'/photos/', 'post', $attachment);
```

But this does not work, because I think  user_id is read as a album id.

What is the proper url for posting to user's photos when I have a user id?

Where can I find the list of all these "url"s for different graph actions?

Note:User has granted publish and offline permissions to the app.

Comment: offline_access is removed. Read: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Answer (score 0):

As long as the token is active you can use `me` so `$result = $facebook->api('/me/photos/', 'post', $attachment);` should still work back when `offline_access` was possible. Even now with 2 month tokens you can use `me`, again *as long as the access token is valid*.